# Select row and change button color

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

[image]In My tableview, cell is custom cell and I have button and label inside it.
lable and button background color is Green.

When I click on Particular row then Button color change and label background color is as it is. Here I used following code to set label background color via layer,

```
cell.lblCountMsg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.lblCountMsg.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:110/255.0 green:189/255.0 blue:82/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
```

but, same code is not working for Button. i tried with layer also

```
cell.btnTeting.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.btnTeting.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:110/255.0 green:189/255.0 blue:82/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
```

but not set green color and also changed the color of selection color.

See, My Screen Shot (Breaking new) is Green.
Please help me to find solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not perfectly get question. Do you want to set green color as background color of button on row click ??

Comment: i already set green button. but when i select raw than chage the color.@Lion

Comment: are you able to change for label but not for button ? is it so?

Comment: @Lion yes i able for change label background color .

Comment: Your code for UIButton background changes appears to be correct. This means that either the wrong button is being set, or the background is being set again later (and erasing your previous changes), or you're using a color that you can't see through your UI (for example, the same color as the highlight, hence it's confused).


Have you tried using breakpoints to make sure the code is only called once, with the correct color, on the correct button, in the correct cell?

Comment: @Zil yes this is current cell.

Comment: @Zil than how can i solve my problem ?

Comment: Have you try my answer?

Comment: I think you're not getting correct cell.first of all get selected cell in tableview's delegate method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" , then change color of button.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` something like,

```
  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

// Here your custom cell's class instead of UITableViewCell
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

}
```

Comment: Edit your question with your `didselecrrow` and `cellforrowatinexpath`. Amd tell me what is the exact issue

Comment: no any code in didselected for related button color

Comment: Your question is not clear enough really. Do you want to change color when row get select? If yes then you must have implemented `didselectrow`

Comment: when i select that time i don't want change the color. i want get as it is. my button background color. my button background color is green.

Answer (score 1):

If you made a UITableViewCell subclass, try overriding the

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
```

method. In this method you can change your views in the cell when the cell is highlighted.

So for example:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
     self.btnTeting.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:110/255.0 green:189/255.0 blue:82/255.0 alpha:1.0]; 
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
@interface SuggestedGroupCell ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnSubScribe;
@end

@implementation SuggestedGroupCell
  - (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
      self.btnSubScribe.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:110/255.0 green:189/255.0 blue:82/255.0 alpha:1.0]; 
  }
@end
```

Comment: how can i set indexPath...=>- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    
    SuggestedGroupCell *cell = (SuggestedGroupCell*)[tblGroupList cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.btnSubScribe.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:110/255.0 green:189/255.0 blue:82/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}

Comment: You need to add the method in your SuggestedGroupCell class.

Comment: btnTesting is in cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change background color of button,remove this line and then try:

```
cell.btnTeting.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:110/255.0 green:189/255.0 blue:82/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
```

But if you want to change button title color you can write code like this:

```
[cell.btnMorePupils setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

Here UIControlState you can take what ever like UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateSelected etc as per your requirement.

Comment: Than simply use this : [cell.btnTeting setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; No need to set layer.backgroundcolor

Comment: i also try this ,.. u create demo and check

Comment: I have used it in my project and working fine. Do not set clearColor, instead of it directly set what ever color you want set. Have you checked whether you have taken outlet of that button? you said you have used custom class.

Comment: In your code, you have set background color in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, now as you want to change background color while selecting button, you have to write code for that in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Actually there are two way you can do it,  1) directly write [cell.btnTeting setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; in didSelectRowAtIndexPath And 2) maintain selected indexpath array and in didSelectRowAtIndexPath add that indextpath in that array and then in cellForRowAtIndexPath put condition like this : if([arSelectedIndex containsObject: indexpath]){[cell.btnTeting setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];} else{ cell.btnTeting.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:110/255.0 green:189/255.0 blue:82/255.0 alpha:1];}